# Image size for universal app ios?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, ios-universal-app

I have a question about using images for universal apps on IOS.

I've created a universal app that works on all iphone devices and ipads. I've placed all the content via storyboard. On a View I have two buttons one on the top space area that is 40 points high and as wide as the view, one on the bottom area also 40 points high and as wide as the view and an image that is a square (A x A) in the middle of the view, the image is constrained by horizontal and vertical (For it to stay always aligned in the middle of the view).

(I understand that if I use an image that is 100 points by 100 points image at 1x, I need to create two other images at 200 points by 200 points for 2x and 300 by 300 for 3x.)

1) So if I constrain the UIImage container by height and width equal to 100 by 100, it will be 100 by 100 points in all devices. But I want it to use as much space as possible. That would mean that on iphone 5 - 6s+ it would always be 100 by 100, it would look smaller on every growing screen. It would also mean that I would need to make it bigger for Ipad (Storyboard changing to regular regular to change UIImage container size for ipad, ex. increase it to 300 x 300). Put once I make it bigger, the image I have will be to small for that size therefore turn blurry or pixelated.

Right?

2) If I would like to be able to use as much space as possible I thought of using the following method. Constraining the UIImage to be equal width as the view but reducing its multiplier to 0.9 or 0.8 (Therefore making it smaller then the view width) and placing an aspect ratio of 1:1(To maintain it square). That way taking advantage of most of the view space that is free, and In all the devices it would always seem filling the same space. However the problem would be that the image would have to be different sizes. (Ex. iphone 5 = 150 x 150, on iphone 6 = 250 x 250, on iphone 6+ = 320 x 320 ans on ipad 600 x 600).

so If I make an image that in 2x that is 150 x 150, when its used on the iphone 6 it would be distorted or pixelated and the same for for the rest.

So can someone help me understand what I should do? or link a tutorial?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the best way to solve this problem would be to make a much larger image and let the constraints resize it. That way, you've covered your bases if new resolutions are developed, or with the current varying sizes. A much larger image would not look bad if it was compressed into a smaller space, but you might lose some details.

Comment: Ok thanks SharkbaitWhoHaha. However I noticed that when using a larger image when compressed to a smaller container by constraints Images lose some detail as you say but also turn a bit blurry, specially on edges.